# Is there a way to include an external .js file in this php code?

Tags: javascript, php

Would it be possible to add an external .js file to put in this current image position that I have set up right now? I'm fairly new to javascript and php so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<div style=\"margin-bottom:50px;clear:both\">";
    if ($result == 8) {echo "<div style=\"width:300px;height:250px;background-color:#f6f6dd;margin-left:10px;margin-bottom:20px;\">";

**echo "<!-- No script tag  --> 
<a href=\"http://" target=\"_blank\"><img border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" src=\"myadspt.png\" alt=\"Ad spot text goes here\"></a>";**

echo "</div>";}
```

Sorry I should have mentioned this part before as well. This .php code is for a newsletter with ad positions inside of it. The .js file that needs to be placed in this .php code is an .swf ad uploaded onto an external news site (I'll call it "SITE A") In "SITE A", the ad has it's own .js script that goes with it.

When this ad is uploaded onto "SITE A", I want it to automatically place into the newsletter, that way it's less hassle for me, and also on "SITE A" it will count the amount of clicks the ad gets each time the newsletter is sent out.

This is the .js script below. Hopefully this helps clarify on what I am wanting to do.

```
<!-- Global Ad Manager javascript file -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.js"></script>


<!-- Ad Manager call to display ads for position testa-->

<script type="text/javascript">
TNCMS.AdManager.render
({
domain: 'www.mysite.com',
secureDomain: 'mysite-dot-com.',
section: testa',
region: 'test',
slot: '1'
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Is the JavaScript file accessible by clients?  `<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>`

Comment: PHP executes on the server, JS executes on the client. Your PHP code cannot invoke a JS function, or vice versa. PHP **can** embed the actual JS code in the page, or output a `<script src="...">` to get the browser to load it, though.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with javascript? Maybe there is a solution with php and you do not need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

just break out of the php using the php tags, I wouldn't use echo and just simply use the script tag.
This is an html tag and not php code.

```
<?php    
//your php code here
?>
<script src="http://url.com/path/script.js"></script>
```

It is recomended to have this into your "head" tag but you can have it in the body of your document (this is not a good practice).

Comment: While "inside" PHP, just like that? *Hm*

Comment: Using something like this `echo '<script src="http://url.com/path/script.js"></script>';`, or `$jsScript = '<script src="http://url.com/path/script.js"></script>'; echo $jsScript;`

Answer (score 0):

PHP only prints HTML. So whatever you want to be done using HTML, you just have to `echo` that HTML using PHP. So for this case:

```
echo '<script src="http://url.com/path/script.js"></script>';
```